# How to call Gtk+ 3 from Cython

Tags: gtk, cython, gtk3

On a fairly stock Debian/Ubuntu Distribution, Python 2 (or 3); Cython installed via pip (`sudo python -m pip install cython`)

How do I make calls to the gtk3 C api?

Do I need any gtk devel packages? For example `libgtk3.0-cil-dev`?

I would really appreciate a code example, possibly the equivalent calls as exemplified in [A trivial application](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s05.html#id-1.2.3.7.5).

I half-expect that I could only do it after declaring the whole api with  [Cython External Declarations](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/external.html#external-declarations)

Answer (score 1):

GTK+, like other libraries in the G* stack, are usually accessed through their own bindings — namely, [PyGObject](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject). PyGObject uses the introspection data generated by GTK+ itself to dynamically call functions of the GTK+ API, as well as exposing the GObject type system as Python classes.

Comment: Ill try that, I assumed that using the python gtk bindings and compiling them as cython would be headache/error city.